# Is it possible that 2 synchronized methods of an object are accessible by 2 threads at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading

This question was asked to me in an interview. Before I had told him this,

> Once a thread enters any synchronized method on an instance, no other
>   thread can enter any other synchronized method on the same instance.

Consider the snippet:

***Q1:***

```
public class Q1 {
    int n;
    boolean valueSet = false;

    synchronized int get() {
        while (!valueSet)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        System.out.println("Got: " + n);
        valueSet = false;
        notify();
        return n;
    }

    synchronized void put(int n) {
        while (valueSet)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }
        this.n = n;
        valueSet = true;
        System.out.println("Put: " + n);
        notify();
    }
}
```

***Producer1:***

```
public class Producer1 implements Runnable {

    Q1 q;

    Producer1(Q1 q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            q.put(i++);
        }

    }
}
```

***Consumer1***

```
public class Consumer1 implements Runnable {

    Q1 q;

    Consumer1(Q1 q) {
        this.q = q;
        new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            q.get();
        }

    }

}
```

***PC1:***

```
public class PC1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Q1 q = new Q1();
        new Producer1(q);
        new Consumer1(q);
        System.out.println("Press Control-C to stop.");

    }
}
```

So, he asked as soon as you have created this thread `new Producer1(q)`, then according to you, the `synchronized int get()` method must have been locked by the same thread, i.e, by `new Producer1(q)` when it accessed `synchronized int put()`. I said yes.

But I checked in eclipse, get is callable by `new Consumer1(q)`. The program works perfect.

Where am I going wrong?

***O/P:***

[image]

Comment: What does `wait()` do?

Comment: @chrylis: My understanding: wait( ) tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some
other thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).

Comment: @chrylis `wait()` is doing wait...for another thread no be notified with

Comment: Bahramdun: How can wait be even called when it is inside the synchronised method which has been locked by new Producer1
(q) thread?

Comment: wait() goes the thread to sleep till the other threads notified this thread.

Comment: Short answer: Each thread can call `wait` while the other thread is waiting for it to do so.

Answer (score 6):

The call to `wait()` will release the monitor for the time waiting.

That's what is documented for `Object.wait():`

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. **The thread
>   releases ownership of this monitor** and waits until another thread
>   notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up
>   either through a call to the notify method or the
>   notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can
>   re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

Comment: No, this is not the answer. You haven't really understood the question.

Comment: @Shirgill: evidently nobody here understands your question then.

Answer (score 1):

> Once a thread enters any synchronized method on an instance, no other
>   thread can enter any other synchronized method on the same instance.

What you forgot to add here is *"except if the lock is released"*.

...and it is the case in your example, when calling `wait`.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) specify :

> The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another
>   thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up
>   either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method.

Since the lock is released, you step in the other method (and the condition is true because the boolean was modified). Once in the other method, you release the lock again, then call notify and you wake up the old thread which terminates (re-modify boolean to pass the condition in other method, and notify). That way you step between both methods *ad-infinitum*.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari when the thread is inside `wait()`, it is as if it was not inside `synchronized`.

Comment: @alain: But don't you think that prior to getting within that wait which you have mentioned, it(the thread) must have encountered that synchronized keyword of the method.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari Yes, but the wait releases it as specified in the quote at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`wait()` and `notify()` is acts as a signal between threads, to control the threads to do or to not do the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The program works perfect because here 2 threads (`Producer`, `Consumer`) which fight for the one lock (monitor). When `Consumer` aquires the lock (`Q1` object) then `Producer` is waiting for the lock. When `Consumer` finishes his work it release the lock. Consumer releases the lock also when wait() method has been called, because `wait()` sets thread to Waiting state with lock release. It's time for `Producer` to aquire the lock and does his work. When `Producer` thread `notify()` calls then `Consumer` continue his work (when aquired the lock). The same is right for `Producer`.

Resume: `Q1` object is a lock for all threads. If it aquired someone then others are blocked and the answer is - it not possible to get an access at the same time to the `get()`, `put()` methods more then 2 threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question is ambiguous.  (E.g., what does "accessible" mean?)

IMO, a good interview question should not have a right answer and a wrong answer.  A good interview question should be a conversation starter, that gives you an opportunity to show how much you know about the subject.

When I am asking the interview questions, I like a candidate who can see through the question, and get down to the underlying mechanism.  E.g.,

```
What the JLS guarantees is that no two threads can be _synchronized_
on the same instance at the same time...
```

Then we could explore questions like, how could two threads enter the same `synchronized` method at the same time?  (e.g., synchronized on different instances), how could two threads be in the same synchronized method for the same instance at the same time (one of them could be in a wait() call), ...

Answer (score -3):

A thread can not access a synchronized block of code unless it has aquired a lock on the object that guards the block. In your case, the `synchronized` keyword uses the lock of the object in which it has been declared. So as long as a thread is executing `get()`, no other thread can execute the `put()`.

If you apply this, when put() sets the value, it notifies consumer which accepts the value. The code should work even after you have removed the wait() and notify() calls from both get and put methods

Comment: No it won't. You can try it if you want.